# How to serve Flask and Apache on a single port on web server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, flask, mod-wsgi

Is it possible to set up Flask with Apache such that some URL paths link to a flask  server and others link to an Apache server?

### Example:

1. *Main page:*
   https://blackfynnpythonlink.ml/simple_heart/
   Apache server gets called and the built site gets sent to the user
2. *Python functions for javascript to call*:  https://blackfynnpythonlink.ml/api/
   Flask server takes HTTPS requests and uses them to call a python API and return the results as HTTPS response

### Case Specific:

In my specific case I have a javascript front end that needs to make calls to a python API. I used to do this with a *separate* server running Flask but I have been told this is inefficient and not secure so I am trying to merge the two together.

Front end Repo: https://github.com/Tehsurfer/MPB

Back end Repo: https://github.com/Tehsurfer/Physiome-Blackfynn-API

Comment: I probably should add that don't know if it's possible to add multiple receiving ports to an AWS server, as that would also be a fix for my specific case.

Comment: Would a solution using subdomains work for you? I mean, having https://blackfynnpythonlink.ml and https://api.blackfynnpythonlink.ml, for example?

Comment: Yes it could do actually. Thanks I didn't think to try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said it was a valid answer, you could [check the following question](https://serverfault.com/questions/195611/how-do-i-redirect-subdomains-to-a-different-port-on-the-same-server), where people explain ways to redirect subdomains to a different port on the same server.

A valid way to do this (mentioned in one of the answers) is to use [name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html). That way, you have the clean urls, and Apache manages the ports.

Comment: It's not the answer I wanted to hear, but it's the one I deserve :D.